# How to migrate Java child class to Kotlin when the parent class implements Parcelable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parcelable

I have decided to migrate to Kotlin from Java. I have the following Data Object Structure in my java app.

```
public class User implements Parcelable{
private String uuid;
private String name; 
// ..etc constructors getters setters and parcelable  implementation

}
```

and

```
public class Student extends User{

    private String grade; 
    // ..etc constructors getters setters and parcelable  implementation

    }
```

How can I achieve this in kotlin?
Thank you

Comment: Kotlin tutorial has a section on classes. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#creating-classes-and-instances

Comment: I know how to create classes in Kotlin, I just want to know how to make inheritance like what I did

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html

Comment: Your problem is probably not related to the inheritance per-se but with the `Parceleable` implementation. Please review my edit and see if it makes your question better.

Comment: @cutiko thank you for editing the question now it is more clear to everyone I think

Comment: I've no idea what is being asked here. What did you try? And more importantly what didn't work? And how?

Comment: I just need to create a data class which implements parcelable and make inheritance to create sub classes of this main class

Comment: @Falzao Data classes can't inherit from each other. (note that nowhere in your question you say you want/need data classes). Just make them regular classes.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to go something like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
 val uuid:String,
 val name:String):Parcelable
```

Research how to do inheritance yourself please.(It should be the clear from the above code snippet though)

Comment: when I write @Parcelize data class Student(var grade:String):User() it wont work

Comment: You have to pass values to the constructor of User(), something like:
@Parcelize data class Student(....):User(uuid="something",name="something"),Parcelable